# What should the results of a convolution be?

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm using convnetjs to build an interactive tutorial (as I learn it myself).  I have a simple 9x9 image of an 'X' and a convolutional layer with one of the filters as a 3x3 '\'... [image]

I expected the results to be different.  I expected the circled result on the right to be (-1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)/9 = 0.77 instead of 7.1.

What else is happening that results in 7.1?  Is this due to biases?  I also expected the whole result to show highest numbers along the '\' diagonal, since the filter is that shape which would match the '\' part of the 'X'.

UPDATE: I expected the results to be the following.  The biases appear to be an array [0.1,0.1,0.1].  What is the calculation that yeilds the above results (for at least the upper left pixel), instead of the below?

[image]

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/convnetjs/build/convnet-min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    // Initialize an input that is 9x9 and initialized with zeroes.
    let inputVol = new convnetjs.Vol(9, 9, 1, 0.0);

    // Manually set the input weights from zeroes to a 'X'...
    inputVol.w = [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1];

    // Define the layers
    let layers = [];
    layers.push({
      type: 'input',
      out_sx: 9,
      out_sy: 9,
      out_depth: 1
    });
    layers.push({
      type: 'conv',
      sx: 3,
      pad: 0,
      filters: 3,
      stride: 1,
      activation: 'relu'
    });
    let net = new convnetjs.Net();
    net.makeLayers(layers);

    let convLayer = net.layers[1];
    let convLayerFilters = convLayer.filters;

    // Set filters manually
    // looks like a '\'
    convLayerFilters[0].w = [1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1];
    // looks like a 'X'
    convLayerFilters[1].w = [1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1];
    // looks like a '/'
    convLayerFilters[2].w = [-1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1];

    // Run the net
    net.forward(inputVol);

    // Prints '7.1' instead of '0.77'.  Why???
    console.log(net.layers[1].out_act.w[0]);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should include code, right now you want us to guess what code produced these results.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro It is more a question of how a convnet works rather than my code using it.  But to help troubleshoot, I've edited the post to include the minimal code.

Comment: The question is not about how a convnet works in general, you have specific code, and results and you are asking why they are different. A convolutional layer just does convolution plus a bias and an activation. The code you have might just be doing something extra and you have to look at the code for that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is happening because of biasing so that it stays in the range defined.

Bias is the value that you can add to each element in a convolution result to add additional influence from neighbouring pixels. Since with certain convolutions it is possible to get negative numbers (which are not representable in a 0–255 format), bias prevents the signal from drifting out of range. You can choose to add a bias of 127 or 128 to allow some negative numbers to be representable (with an implicit +127 or +128 in their value).